# Hardcore bit of a one way function

Tags: complexity-theory, cryptography

Let $b:\{0,1\}^*\mapsto \{0,1\}$, be a hardcore bit of a one way function $f$. I want to show that $\vert Pr_{x\in U_n}[b(x)=1]-Pr_{x\in U_n}[b(x)=0]\vert=n^{-\omega(1)}$. Intuitively, it looks correct as if it is not the case then the bit is not hardcore, but I do not have any ideas how to proceed with the proof. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try using the definitions.

Comment: Whats $\omega(1)$ supposed to mean? A constant?

Comment: If you don't understand what you need to prove, you won't be able to prove it!

Comment: The notation $\omega(1)$ stands for an arbitrary function tending to infinity.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that as stated the statement is wrong, perhaps you mean $b(f(x))$ inside the probability?

Comment: No this is correct as $b$ always acts on $x$

Comment: Anyways it can be proved by using definitions I get that

Comment: Let $f$ be a one way function whose first bit is always 1. Define $g(x,r)=(f(x),r)$ and define $b(y,r)=<y,r>$ (Goldreich-Levin) if $y$ starts with 1 and $b(y,r)=0$  if $y$ starts with 0. On a random string $b$ is $0$ with probability $3/4$, yet it is hardcore for $g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, I'll make my comment an answer. Under the current formulation the statement is wrong, a hardcore bit can be non-negligibly biased towards $0$ or $1$, i.e. $\Pr_{x\sim U_n}\left[b(x)=0\right]\ge \frac{1}{2}+n^{-c}$ infinitely often. However $b$ of course cannot be biased on the image of $f$. To illustrate this point, suppose there exists a (length preserving) one way function and let $g(x,r)=(f(x),r)$, where $(x,r)\in\{0,1\}^n$. Also assume that the leftmost bit of $f(x)$ is always $1$ (one can always construct a new one way function from $f$ satisfying this).

Now define:

$b(y,r)=\begin{cases}
\langle y,r\rangle, & y_1=1 \\
0, & y_1=0
\end{cases}
$

where $y,r\in\{0,1\}^n$ and $\langle y,r \rangle=\sum\limits_{i=1}^ny_ir_i\pmod 2$. Since the leftmost bit of $f(x)$ is always $1$, $b$ is hardcore for $g$ (direct application of Goldreich-Levin). Note that for every $y\neq 0$ exactly half the strings $r\in\{0,1\}^n$ satisfy $\langle y,r\rangle = 0$. We conclude that $\Pr_{(y,r)\sim U_{2n}}\left[b(y,r)=0\right]\ge\frac{3}{4}$. This bias was made possible by the fact the $b$ can be easy outside the image of $f$. The statement is true if we instead require no bias for $b(f(x))$ where $x$ is random.

Comment: The question statement is from one assignment problem. If the question is wrong then I do not know.. The problem statement is exactly what I wrote.. What you are saying is correct...So, I accept.